# Short story featuring two miners (one female, one male) who were prospecting on another planet while wearing powered suits

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

The story took place maybe on Venus. The male miner goes a little crazy and starts hunting his partner. They work for a large company and need to make a big find soon before they run out of resources.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: I think this is it ! Thank you all !

Comment: If [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/275380/122024) is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 7):

Could this be *[Tin Marsh](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?195781)* by Michael Swanwick?

Our protagonist, Patang is prospecting on Venus with her partner MacArthur. After an accident, he realises that his implants (which normally prevent him from killing her) have malfunctioned.

He leads her on a merry chase across the surface of the planet. He keeps pointing his mining laser at her and she keeps getting a "laser hazard" warning pop up on her internal screen.

> She came to seconds later. But it was like opening a book in the middle or stepping into an interactive an hour after it began. She had no idea what had happened or how it affected her.
>
> MacArthur was strapping her into her muscle suit.
>
> “Is everything okay?” she murmured. “Is something wrong?”
>
> “I was going to kill you, Patang. But killing you isn’t enough. You have to suffer first.”

Gardner Dozois was a big fan of this story and it was published in *The Year's Best Science Fiction: Twenty-Fourth Annual Collection*, *The Mammoth Book of Best New Science Fiction: 20th Annual Collection* and *The Very Best of the Best: 35 Years of The Year's Best Science Fiction*

Comment: Why does he require implants to keep from killing her?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Because he's mentally unstable and because she's been mercilessly taunting him for months, intentionally trying to break his spirit